# Fresh Symphony installation stuck in loop

Tags: frameworks, symphony-cms

i cannot seem to install symphony on my server, i just fetched the most recent version as a .tar file, uploaded and extracted.

I installed it at a sub domain to test it:

```
http://symphony.domain.com/
```

So after the upload, i go to the url, and i get a infinite redirect browser issue, the url is now:

```
http://symphony.domain.com/index.php/?symphony-page=403.shtml/
```

Same thing happens if i go to

```
http://symphony.domain.com/app/check.php
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your web server configuration? That URL looks like you might be getting a custom error page redirection--perhaps from `httpd.conf` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue just now. My issue had something to do with the JIT image manipulation. For now, try commenting out this rule in your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^image\/(.+\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp))$ extensions/jit_image_manipulation/lib/image.php?param=$1 [B,L,NC]
```